# App updates and Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have an app that is available on the App Store. The app uses Core Data to allow users to store settings and favorites.

I need to deliver an update to the app. The update WILL NOT change anything about the Core Data store. However, this is the first update I have delivered and I am concerned over whether the Core Data store will be preserved when users apply the update. Anybody have experience with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Apple Doc: [Files Saved During App Updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18)

When a user downloads an app update, iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the following directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:

Application_Home/Documents

Application_Home/Library

Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely on them being present after an update.

This means that coreDate persistentStore is stored in the `Documents` directory , so it will be perserved.